# Releasing after pushing in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

So I have the following code where I am releasing an object after pushing it to another view. When I analyse it I get the error  - Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller. Would anyone know how to fix this? I've tried so many options each time getting a different memory leak

```
- (void)showCurrentArticle:(id)sender {
    if(animating) 
        return; //it is already there
    animating = YES;
    JsonViewController *newsController = [(JsonViewController *)[self.newsNavController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]retain];
    newsNavController.title = @"Parliament";
    Item *currentItem = (Item *)[self.fetchedObjectsArray objectAtIndex:currentItemIndex];
    NSString * urlString = [CONST_FEED_DISCRIPTION_URL stringByAppendingString:currentItem.guid];
    [newsController initWithURLString:urlString date:currentItem.date];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newsController animated:YES];
    [newsController release];
}
```

Comment: Is it a project you just started? If yes, consider seriously moving to ARC, it makes your life **much** easier

Comment: Nope.. Its a project that needs to support older versions of ios.. and its an old project that im debugging atm

Comment: What older versions of iOS?  ARC supports iOS 4 onwards.  There's really very little point in supporting iOS 3 or below.

Comment: A bit off topic, but I've never seen calling an `init...` method on an already allocated, instantiated object before. Can I ask why you're doing that?

Comment: What are you doing with `-initWithURLString:date:`??? Are you just adding a url? Then you should call it `addURL...`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code takes a view controller that's already present in the navigation stack, reinitialises it, then pushes it onto the stack again.  This doesn't seem right at all.  You probably should be creating a new view controller.  What's the background on this?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes like you adviced i initialised a new view controller and pushed it. The reason i wanted to do it the way i did it earlier was to get a navigation bar on top but now i manually added a bar so it works fine

Answer (score 1):

You are popping, change a title, than you are doing an initialization...

Decide if you will do deep clone of `JsonViewController` (alloc, init, copy field values) or just reference copy (retain). It will be mess later if you try to mix.

Answer (score 1):

Your retain and release of the newsController object are unnecessary. That is why you are getting the warning. It looks like newsController is owned by the newsNavController object, which will retain it. The only reason you would need to retain newsController in this code is if you needed to use it outside the scope of this method. Since you don't need to retain it, you don't need to release it, hence the error. You may be assuming that the `-initWithURLString:date:` method is incrementing the retain count, but it is only new, alloc, and retain that do this. You should probably rename that method to not use the term init to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with `-initWithURLString:date:`??? Are you just adding a url? Then you should call it `addURL...`... If you really initialize it again, you set the pointer of the newsController variable to a new object. The first object it pointed to gets lost -> leak.

I assume you named the init method wrong and just add a url to a controller, which is already in the stack and add it again with a higher retain count, but still the very same object.

Don't do this. Copy the object or better - create a new instance of the viewController!!!